# Add language entry in Windows 10 language list

Tags: c++, windows, configuration, mfc

I need to create a new language entry in Windows 10 in runtime (specifically *Chinese* and *Japanese*) using C++ and MFC framework.

See picture below:

[image]

I have implemented a virtual keyboard and a language settings dialog which according to a selected language, changes input language. I have used LoadKeyboardLayout and ActivateKeyboardLayout WINAPI functions and works for other languages but not in Chinese and Japanese (it needs that both languages are in windows 10 language list to work) so I would like to know if there are any way to add both languages dinamically in windows 10 language list.

See code below:

```
void OSKSettingsDialog::SetKeyboardInputLanguage(LPCWSTR idLanguage)
{
    HKL desiredhk1 = LoadKeyboardLayout(idLanguage, 0);

    ActivateKeyboardLayout(desiredhk1, KLF_SETFORPROCESS);
}

    SetKeyboardInputLanguage(L"00000409"); //input locale id of english language(WORKS FINE)        
    SetKeyboardInputLanguage(L"00000804"); //input locale id of chinese (FAILS)
    SetKeyboardInputLanguage(L"00000411"); //input locale id of japanese (FAILS)
    SetKeyboardInputLanguage(L"00000816"); //input locale id of portuguese (WORKS FINE)
```

Are there any way to do it?

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: This feels like an XY-Problem; why do you want to write code to install/select a system wide language pack?  If it's just for your application search "MSDN MUI"; if for many systems use the built-in system management tools.

Comment: I have implemented a virtual keyboard and a language settings dialog which according to a selected language, changes input language. I have  used **LoadKeyboardLayout** and **ActivateKeyboardLayout** WINAPI functions and works for other languages but not in Chinese and Japanese (it needs that both languages are in windows 10 language list to work) so I would like to know if there are any way to add both languages dinamically in windows 10 language list.

Comment: So this *is* an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) then. It appears that your calls to `LoadKeyboardLayout` and/or `ActivateKeyboardLayout` fail. You should ask about those API calls instead.

Comment: I have added my code into description

Comment: You can only load an input locale for a language the user has installed in their system. If a user decides not to install a language, it is unlikely that they would want to use that language's input locale. Why do you believe that your application needs to switch to an input locale the user has decided against using?

Comment: `00000409` and `00000816` are English-US and Portuguese, they both use the same code page and they likely work on your system for keyboard input. You need additional download and installation for other languages.

Comment: `00000411` and `00000804` probably have IME, which has different layout codes... for example `04110411` for Google Japanese IME